# Two shape merge as union using vba in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to merge two same shapes into one by using union property. While compiling the code it shows method 'executemso' of object 'commandbar' failed. I'm new in vba so it would be great if someone help me to fix this.

```
Sub ShapesUnion()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes

            If shp.Fill.Type = msoFillSolid Then
            With shp.Duplicate
                .Left = shp.Left
                .Top = shp.Top
            End With
            End If
            shp.Select
            CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapesUnion")
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Just as well it wouldn't compile by the way. Your code would have created ZILLIONS of shapes and run until your computer fell over.  You're duplicating each filled shape on the slide, but in duplicating it, you're creating another filled shape ... which you'll then duplicate and anon.  And the .Select line will only select the most recently created shape, not two shapes as required for merge.  Instead, create an array or collection of the solid filled shapes on the slide, then step through the array/collection to process the shapes one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `MergeShapes` method to achieve this:

```
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape

Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 100, 100, 50, 50)
Set shp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, 100, 100, 50, 50)
Call ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes.Range(Array(shp1.ZOrderPosition, shp2.ZOrderPosition)).MergeShapes(msoMergeCombine)
```

Comment: Is there a way to generalise this? So say I am adding shapes to the slide via VBA but don't know how many there will be in advance.
I have tried storing the shapes in an array and naming the shapes and putting a string of names into the array (in line with the guidance here: ) but neither work.