# Merge shapes for unknown number of shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I come to you for wisdom once again!

I've written some code that inserts several shapes (dynamic number depending on user selection) and as a final step, need to merge them using the MergeShapes method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.mergeshapes

This solution works if you have a set number of shape objects:
[Two shape merge as union using vba in powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023622/two-shape-merge-as-union-using-vba-in-powerpoint/46025003)

But I cannot get this working for an unknown number of shapes.

I have tried:

- Storing all shapes in an array in an array first and trying to merge that

  ```
  ReDim UnionArray(1 To ShapeCounter)

  For i = 1 To ShapeCounter
    Set UnionArray(i) = TempSlide.Shapes("Wrapper" & ShapeCounter)
  Next i

  TempSlide.Shapes(UnionArray).MergeShapes (msoMergeUnion)
  ```
- Building a string of the shape names and trying to work with that

  ```
  Dim ShapeNamesArray             As String

  ShapeNamesArray = """" & "Wrapper1" & """"

  For i = 2 To ShapeCounter
    ShapeNamesArray = ShapeNamesArray & ", " & """" & "Wrapper" & i & """"
  Next i
  ```

The above produces a string like: "Wrapper1", "Wrapper2", "Wrapper3"

```
   TempSlide.Shapes.Range(Array(ShapeNamesArray)).MergeShapes (msoMergeUnion)
```

EDIT: I have also tried building a string of the ZOrderPositions.
If you ...Range(Array(5, 6, 8)).MergeShapes... it works, but not if you do ArrZOrders = "5, 6, 8" and then ...Range(Array(ArrZOrders)).MergeShapes...

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a working version which selects each of the shapes and then uses the CommandBars.Execute method, but I really hate using selection, so a more elegant solution would be appreciated!

Dim i                           As Integer

    ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Wrapper1").Select Replace:=msoTrue
    For i = 2 To ShapeCounter
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Wrapper" & i).Select Replace:=msoFalse
    Next i

      CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapesUnion")

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (using a zero-based array)

```vb
Dim arr(0 To 2)
    
arr(0) = "Rectangle 10"
arr(1) = "Rectangle 9"
arr(2) = "Rectangle 8"
    
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    .Shapes.Range(arr).MergeShapes msoMergeUnion
End With
```