# how to rename shape after two shape merge as a union?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am a newbie in PowerPoint VBA. I want to merge two shapes using VBA. So I search in the web & found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025003/17766045

```
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape

Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 100, 100, 50, 50)
Set shp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, 100, 100, 50, 50)
Call ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes.Range(Array(shp1.ZOrderPosition, shp2.ZOrderPosition)).MergeShapes(msoMergeCombine)
```

But I don't configure how to rename that merge shape.

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Name = "TEST"` ?

Comment: Sir, in my project there are other shapes also & this merge shape is not on top or bottom in the selection pane its lies between other shapes.

Answer (score 1):

> > this merge shape is not on top or bottom in the selection pane its lies between other shapes

When you merge multiple shapes, it creates a new shape, and newly created shapes will be at the top of the Z-order.

For some odd reason, .MergeShapes doesn't return a reference to the newly created shape, but since it'll be at the top of the Z-order, you can reference it as shown in the code sample below:

```
Sub thing()
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape
Dim aShapeArray As Variant
Dim oRange As ShapeRange

Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 100, 100, 50, 50)
Set shp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, 100, 100, 50, 50)
' Using shape names rather than z-order position to fill the array and
' breaking the merge step into several simpler/easier to understand steps:
Set aShapeArray = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range(Array(shp1.Name, shp2.Name))
Set oRange = aShapeArray
oRange.MergeShapes (msoMergeCombine)
    
 ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count).Name = "BINGO!"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir. Now it's perfectly working as I wanted.