# Crop bottom of pictures

Tags: vba, powerpoint

My goal is to crop pictures so that their bottom part is a clean-cut of a horizontal rectangle. Imagine a picture on a slide, and a rectangle covering its lower part -- the picture should be cropped as if the rectangle was still covering it.

The working code to crop the top part:

```vb
Dim oSh As Shape

oSh.PictureFormat.Crop.ShapeTop = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Horizontal Shape For Upper Crop").Top + ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Horizontal Shape For Upper Crop").Height
```

Cropping the bottom is different. I think I tried every combination of `.Crop.ShapeBottom` and `.CropBottom` with `oSh.Height`, `oSh.Top`, and the "Horizontal Shape for Lower Crop"'s Height and Top properties. Any combination of sums and/or differences crops too much or too little.

Is there a direct way to crop the picture to the height I want "by the amount"?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `oSh.PictureFormat.Crop.ShapeHeight = 400`? Of course make the 400 your desired height. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.crop.shapeheight

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same need for a macro I developed, and like you I could not find a way to crop the image. So I turned to Merge-Fragmenting the image with a shape and then deleting the exceeding resulting shape (as there will be 2). In your case probably it would be enough to use `msoMergeSubtract` instead (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/library-reference/msomergecmd-enumeration-office)).This is not the canonical answer, but it worked in my case. You can implement this by creating the shape before this loop, in my case it exists already. I adapted [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70488893/18247317) to my needs.

```
Dim focusImage As PowerPoint.shape
Dim focusCrop As PowerPoint.shape
Dim pastedFocusCrop As PowerPoint.shape
Dim pastedFocusImage As PowerPoint.shape


Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(slideIndex + 1,
PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank)

  Set focusImage =
pptPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("focusImage")
  Set focusCrop =
pptPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("focusCrop")


                    focusCrop.Copy
                    pptSlide.Shapes.Paste
                    Set pastedFocusCrop = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)


                    focusImage.Copy
                    pptSlide.Shapes.Paste
                    Set pastedFocusImage = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)


                Dim aShapeArray As PowerPoint.ShapeRange 'Variant
                Dim oRange As PowerPoint.ShapeRange


                    Set aShapeArray = pptPresentation.Slides(pptPresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes.Range(Array(pastedFocusCrop.name,
pastedFocusImage.name))
                    Set oRange = aShapeArray
                    oRange.MergeShapes (msoMergeFragment)

                    '' Set the name of the merged shape

                    pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count - 1).name =
"CroppedImage"
'                    pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count).Name =
"MergedShape2"
                    pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count).Delete
```