# Powerpoint VBA Macros - "En-masse" rotation, magnification, and shape-based trimming of photos

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have sets of photos I need to rotate, change magnification, and then crop to a rectangular shape. As you probably know, PowerPoint has the bad habit of cropping images based on their "rotated shape" instead of giving out a nice orthogonal rectangle after an image has been rotated.

I only found two solutions online -- one is to copy-paste as image, the other is to make a rectangle on the shape, then use the "intersect" feature of shapes to make a pseudo-crop. The first option doesn't work well in my case, because the photos lose a ton of quality (they start as 4k pictures); I tried resizing them to a bigger size before doing the copy-paste, and while this gives a "pasted image" of good quality, it also increases the size of the file by something like 20x fold. So...not really an option.

The second option works quite well, but unfortunately I'm struggling quite a bit to find out a way to do a mass-cropping with it. My idea was to dump all the pictures in one slide, rotate them, then align the photos horizontally, place two horizontal lines so the user can adjust the height of the photos relative to the lines, and then use a macro to create rectangles that have the same .Top and .Height as the "reference" lines, and intersect those rectangles on each shape. This actually worked, and I got the photos cropped in an apparent straight line both at their top and at their bottom.

Two problems arise afterwards. One is that, after the top/bottom crop, I then tried doing the same thing: I redistributed the photos vertically, added two vertical "reference lines", and tried to make those "cropping rectangles" again. Problem is, powerpoint's reference for the .Top and .Height of the photos is not at the "visible" Top/Bottom of the photos, but rather still remembers the rotated-shape's values. This means that when I create these new rectangles I can get the width right, but their heights will be messed up, because I asked the macro to make the rectangles at a .Top and .Height value that is the .Top/.Height of the "shape" (which is higher than the visible part, i.e. the part that remained after the first cropping earlier).

The other problem is that if I want to redistribute the photos after cropping them, assuming I could find a fix for the previous problem, I would end up with photos that still have the "original" (rotated) .Top/.Left values, and therefore the alignment would, again, refer to those values instead of referring to the "visible" part of the photos (which is the one that I want to align, obviously).

Now maybe there are some geometric calculations that can be made to re-assess the "visible" .Top/.Left (in fact, surely there are), but it's getting really frustrating to have to work with this problem. So here I am, asking: is there a better way of doing this? The easiest "solution" would be to rotate the images outside of powerpoint, so the rotation-related mess goes away, and the rest of the "en-mass" cropping can be done smoothly. Still, in my situation there would be several advantages (for the purpose of what I'm doing) to doing the rotation in powerpoint instead of outside.

So...does anyone have any better idea to achieve what I need?

Also, on an unrelated note, does anyone know if the "intersect" function was added in later versions of powerpoint? It doesn't seem to appear/work on a certain computer (but works fine on my main one, which runs a more recent version of ppt).

Comment: >> "Also, on an unrelated note, does anyone know if the "intersect" function was added in later versions of powerpoint?"  Yes, it was added a few versions back; sorry, I don't remember exactly when it appeared. 2010 perhaps?

Comment: Welp, at least I got one answer. I guess there isn't much hope for the rest of the issue lol

Comment: So have you not tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785630/crop-bottom-of-pictures/75787759#75787759 to your previous question? By adjusting it with bits from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.rotation you should achieve what you are aiming to.

Comment: Yea, forgot about that one sorry >_>
Unfortunately it seems that I still get the problem with the discrepancy of the "visible shape output" versus the "powerpoint shape output". Gonna try to add a screenshot.

Comment: https://ibb.co/sHK6PvZ
The issue is that if I try to use any kind of "Align" feature with the result I currently get, powerpoint will reference to the "invisible" vertices, and not the "actual image/visible" vertices.

Comment: if you merge a not-rotated shape with a rotated one (following this order) the rotation is reset to 0

Comment: ...mmh? The rotated shape is the image I want to keep, so I always have to merge the rotated shape with the non-rotated shape. I tried every combination of Z_order and every "Merge" option available, the rotated image always disappears when I merge in the opposite order (non-rotated with rotated).